# No tests were found when running Rspec from RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I recently installed RubyMine in my Mac and I am trying to run test cases present in my project by right clicking on the *_spec.rb file and using "Run 'RSpec:...."  option .  But I get the message "no tests were found" .

I am able to run my test cases from RubyMine terminal and from my Mac terminal but not by the option provided by RubyMine ( like explained above)

Can some one please suggest what could be the issue ?

My config is :

- Ruby 2.3.3
- Rails 4.2.11.1
- RubyMine 2020.3.2

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the code of the spec you're trying to run?

Comment: Basically I am using a very big spec file present in my company project and it is running fine from my command line. Let me try to create some hello world Rspec file and I can put it here. But really it seems like a RubyMine config issue

Answer (score 1):

The reasons could be different let's start with this
[image]

go to the folder that includes your specs and make sure to mark as "Test Sources Root"

if this wasn't enough make go to ***Rubymine > Preferances > Ruby SDK and Gems***
and make sure that you are using the right SDK
[image]

if still have problems check the run>Edit configuration and review the configuration of running specs there

Comment: my RSpec test dir is Green in color just like your screen shot , and my ruby version is 2.3.3 like your screen shot. The only diff is I am using ASDF instead of RVM . I will gather more info and will add it in the question soon .

Comment: For me I had to switch to a different version (as above, under Ruby SDK and Gems), press Apply, then switch back to the original version, press Apply again, and then it worked.